# How to do this in cron?

Tags: php, unix, cron

I have no experience with cron or unix so I was wondering if anybody would be kind enough to show me how to write something like:
execute this at 8:30EST March 24 2011, delete the text "I am going camping tomorrow" and put in place the text "I have gone camping". The text would be right between  and . Cron would then upload the program at 8:30est as well.

You can fill in any details I didn't include for the sake of example (like pretend my php file is located C:/User/Billy/Desktop/nice.php). Anybody with a heart of gold willing to help a newbie? :[

Comment: `C:/User/Billy/Desktop/nice.php`...on a Unix system?

Comment: Figure out how to do it out of cron, then add a cron job.

Comment: Bobby, well I thought one would upload the script exacting what to do onto the web host, which runs on unix. Or something-er-other :/. I know people without unix systems are able to do crons hah. Ignacio: I have no idea what the difference is.

Comment: @user6578847: Use @Username, thanks. `I have no idea what the difference is.` I think that's your problem there, you might want to have a look at the basic Unix-Functionality first, before tempering with a *live server*. The Wikipedia page of [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) and [Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) is a very good start.

Comment: This has gotta be a joke.   -1.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the cron job with `at`, though you can't specify timezone AFAIK (so just give the time in the current time zone).

```
at 8:30am March 24 2011
sed -i bak 's/I am going camping tomorrow/I have gone camping/g' C:/User/Billy/Desktop/nice.php
<CTRL-d>
```

Afterwards, you can check with `atq` that the job is queued. You can and should try this in advance, of course. Note that `sed -i bak` makes changes to a file in-place and creates a backup with extension `.bak`.

Comment: And how do I upload? Is it really as simple as that!? I mean how does cron even know where the I am going camping is (thought you need to specify between what and what)? If you look at my profile, my last thread posted about an hour ago, was received with tons of "just use CMS!!" This is making me very giddy lol

Comment: @user657847: You can't upload a cron job like that, you need to do this in a shell (e.g. ssh). [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) goes through the entire file, replacing all occurences, so it doesn't need to know the exact location.

Comment: Well is uploading using a shell easy, and takes little? Also, what if I want to plan for the third and fourth day? How would I replace the 'I have gone camping' with 'Camping is fun', followed by 'Leaving the trip now'? If I want to replace an image code (<img src="blag.png">, and remove "<div id="jersey">" for example, would I need to upload multiple scripts, or can I do all this in one file? All this is saved in a .txt doc, right? Sorry, for the many questions but you've restored my hope in using cron.

Comment: @user657847: No, this command isn't saved in a file, not .txt, not .doc. I repeat: **this command is not saved in a file**. Rather, you need to type this in a shell on an UNIX machine. If you don't have a UNIX shell account, you shouldn't really be asking questions about using cron on UNIX in the first place.

Comment: Well is there an alternative way to update my site frequently automatically? I thought people of all sorts of machines use cron to update their sites

Comment: cron is not a programming tool.

Comment: I hear that's what people use to update their sites though. I mean, a google search would show that people do use cron to pdate their site.

Comment: It's still not a programming tool.